# Phonegap windows 8 develop a native plugin

Tags: c#, cordova, windows-8, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing a plugin for Phonegap and I have some code that works on Windows 8 but is written with c#. It is possible to develop a plugin that includes Windows 8 platform and the code is c# instead of js?

Thanks!

Comment: To my knowledge, no. You'd need to use something like [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) with Portable Class Libraries. This is instead of Phonegap/Cordova.

Comment: Plugins include both JS and Native code. As an example I have a bluetooth printer plugin for iOS and Android. The plugin package includes: 1 JS file for my app to use, 1 JAVA file for the android activity and 1 H/M pair for the iOS class. Cordova's plugin functionality allows the JS code to pass information and calls to the native code and allows the native code to return values back to the JS. here is the doc on windows specific: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_wp8_plugin.md.html#Windows%20Phone%20Plugins